# Unknown encoder 'libx265' when using command in Android studio java

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, video-processing

I try to compress a video using a library and running a FFmpeg command in my android app written in java (although the library is in Kotlin)
I manage to do basic operations but the current one I am going to show you will always fail with the following error code: Unknown encoder 'libx265'

The library expects the input to be a String[] and I assume that there is something going wrong but I cannot find what exactly.

the command line

```
    val query:Array<String> = arrayOf("-i", videoPath , "-c:v" , "libx265" ,"preset", "fast", "-crf", "30", "-tag:v", "hvc1", "-c:a", "eac3", "-b:a", "224k" ,            "$videoPath.mp4");
```

the entire code

```
fun videoCompress(videoPath: String) {
    val query:Array<String> = arrayOf("-i", videoPath , "-c:v" , "libx265" ,"-preset", "fast", "-crf", "30", "-tag:v", "hvc1", "-c:a", "eac3", "-b:a", "224k" , "$videoPath.mp4");

    CallBackOfQuery().callQuery(query, object : FFmpegCallBack {
        override fun statisticsProcess(statistics: Statistics) {
            Log.i("FFMPEG LOG : ", statistics.videoFrameNumber.toString())
        }

        override fun process(logMessage: LogMessage) {
            Log.i("FFMPEG LOG : ", logMessage.text)
        }

        override fun success() {
            Log.d("yyyy", "success: ")
        }

        override fun cancel() {
        }

        override fun failed() {
        }
    })
}
```

[The Log from the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHOAP.png)

what I added to my build.gradle file

```
    implementation 'com.github.SimformSolutionsPvtLtd:SSffmpegVideoOperation:1.0.8'
```

the result (exact)

Unknown encoder 'libx265'

Comment: Can you please execute with `-report` argument (after `"$videoPath.mp4"`), and post the content of the created log file (as text - not as image). I think your FFmpeg in not built with `libx265`, but I have not experience with JAVA and Android.

Comment: Hey I found another way to work around this issue and hopefully have solved it. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Use this library

```
implementation 'com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-full-gpl:4.2.2.LTS'
```

and this command

```
String cmd = "-y -i " + oldPath + " -c:a copy -r 30 -vcodec libx264 -crf 28 -preset ultrafast " + newFile.getPath();
```